# Xamarin cross platform gives error on creating project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, platform

When creating solution, error occurs

**portable-win+net45+wp80+win+monoandroid10+monotouch10+xamarin.ios10**  package does not contains any assembly reference

Error No 1)

[image]

Error No 2)

[image]

I try following solution and many others solutions but noting happens.

enter link description here

I have

1. window 7 32 bit
2. visual studio 2013 ultimate

Give me a better solution, in step by step if possible 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like the Xamarin installation isn't very stable. I'd suggest reinstalling/repairing the install of possible

Comment: I have done this but nothing change

Comment: I would also recommend updating to use visual studio 2017 instead of 2013